# Closing an Infowindow Using Googlemaps API

Tags: javascript

I have read through this problem over and over and tried several different solutions that have been suggested and now I think I've totally gone in the wrong direction. I'm just trying to get the infowindow to close when the next one clicked is opened.

The JSFiddle will show the infowindows pop up when clicking on the marker but opens several if you keep clicking.
https://jsfiddle.net/RaeRae961/dp64cbwv/1/
Here is the code:

```js
(function init() {
  var dataKey = '1n-q5n4aaIn95SM0OGoZ6yDp0aSk4gfWeh0-yILHqAS8';
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 39.7392,
      lng: -104.9903
    },
    zoom: 11
  };

  var energyStarLogo = "energy_star_logo_small.png"
  var starGreen = "http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/00FF0D/"
  var starYellow = "http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/FFF000/"
  var starGrey = "http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/8A8989/"

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  function content(building) {
    {
      content: building.address1
    }
  };

  function determineIcon(building) {
    if (building.energyStarYears.indexOf('2014')) {
      return energyStarLogo;
    }
    // else if (!building.energyStarYears.indexOf('2014'))
    else {
      return starGreen;
    }
    // else{
    //   return starGrey;
    // }
  };

  function addMarker(building_data) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(building_data.lat, building_data.lng),
      icon: determineIcon(building_data)
    });
    // console.log(building_data);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "<p>" + "<strong>Property Name: </strong>" + building_data.propertyname + "</p>" + "<p>" + "<strong>Address: </strong>" + building_data.address + "</p>" + "<p>" + "<strong>Energy Star Score: </strong>" + building_data.energyStarScore + "</p>" + "<p>" + "<strong>Energy Star Years: </strong>" + building_data.energyStarYears + "</p>" + "<p>" + "<strong>Energy Use Intensity (kbtu/sq ft): </strong>" + building_data.energyUseIntensity + "</p>" + "<p>" + "<strong>Property Type: </strong>" + building_data.propertyType + "</p>" + "<p>" + "<strong>Gross Square Footage: </strong>" + building_data.squareFootage + "</p>" + "<p>" + "<strong>Year Built: </strong>" + building_data.yearBuilt + "</p>" + "<p>" + "<strong>Building Website: </strong>" + building_data.website + "</p>"
        // + "<p>" + "<strong>Other Green Certifications / Programs: </strong>" + building_data. + "</p>"
        + "<p>" + "<strong>Top Energy Efficient Strategies: </strong>" + building_data.energyStrategies + "</p>"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }



  function dataCallback(data, tabletop) {
    var benchmarked = data['Benchmarked Buildings'].elements;
    // var allBuildings = data['All Buildings over 10000 sq ft'].elements;

    benchmarked.forEach(function(building) {
      // console.log(building);
      if (building.lat && building.lng) {
        addMarker({
          lat: building.lat,
          lng: building.lng,
          address: building.address1,
          energyStarScore: building.energystarscore,
          energyStarYears: building['energystarcertification-yearscertified'],
          energyUseIntensity: building.weathernormalizedsiteeuikbtuft,
          propertyname: building.propertyname,
          propertyType: building['primarypropertytype-selfselected'],
          squareFootage: building.grosssquarefootage,
          yearBuilt: building.yearbuilt,
          website: building.buldingwebsite,
          // certifications: building.
          energyStrategies: building['whatarethetopthreeefficiencystrategiesyouhaveimplementedinyourbuildingifyourbuildinghasbeenwrittenupasacasestudypleaseincludethelinktoithereoremailittodenvercepdenvergov.org.']
        });
      }
    });
  }

  Tabletop.init({
    key: dataKey,
    callback: dataCallback
  });
})();
```

I'm so new to JS, I know this has been asked several times and I've tried to implement those answers but just cant quite figure this out, please be kind.

Using close() and making infowindow into a global variable will close each window, but then it breaks the tabletop.js (I think) and only pulls up one building address on all markers, so it doesn't pull the correct information.

How can I use the close() method, and make the infowindow into a global variable, but still allow the function to work when pulling the data?

Comment: The first jsFiddle isn't showing the map markers. Provide a version that is functional until you got your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is execute the `infowindow_prev.close()` before opening any infowindow where `infowindow_prev` will have reference to the previously open infowindow.For that you can declare an `infowindow_prev` variable in the `init()` function. Now any inner function in `init()` will have access to the `infowindow_prev` variable (this is called closure check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) link for more info) and inside marker click assign `infowindow_prev` as infowindow so it will have the currently open inforwindow object.

Checkout [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dp64cbwv/3/)

```
enter code here(function init() {
 var dataKey = '1n-q5n4aaIn95SM0OGoZ6yDp0aSk4gfWeh0-yILHqAS8';
  var mapOptions = {
center: {
  lat: 39.7392,
  lng: -104.9903
},
zoom: 11
};

 var energyStarLogo = "energy_star_logo_small.png"
 var starGreen = "http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/00FF0D/"
var starYellow = "http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/FFF000/"
var starGrey = "http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/8A8989/"
var infowindow_prev;
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
   function content(building) {
{content: building.address1}
 };

  function addMarker(building_data) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(building_data.lat, building_data.lng),
  icon: determineIcon(building_data)
});
// console.log(building_data);
 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: "<p>" + "<strong>Property Name: </strong>" + building_data.propertyname + "</p>"
    + "<p>" + "<strong>Address: </strong>" + building_data.address  + "</p>"
    + "<p>" + "<strong>Energy Star Score: </strong>" + building_data.energyStarScore + "</p>"
    + "<p>" + "<strong>Energy Star Years: </strong>" + building_data.energyStarYears + "</p>"
    + "<p>" + "<strong>Energy Use Intensity (kbtu/sq ft): </strong>" + building_data.energyUseIntensity + "</p>"
    + "<p>" + "<strong>Property Type: </strong>" + building_data.propertyType + "</p>"
    + "<p>" + "<strong>Gross Square Footage: </strong>" + building_data.squareFootage + "</p>"
    + "<p>" + "<strong>Year Built: </strong>" + building_data.yearBuilt + "</p>"
    + "<p>" + "<strong>Building Website: </strong>" + building_data.website + "</p>"
    // + "<p>" + "<strong>Other Green Certifications / Programs: </strong>" + building_data. + "</p>"
    + "<p>" + "<strong>Top Energy Efficient Strategies: </strong>" + building_data.energyStrategies + "</p>"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  if(infowindow_prev)
      infowindow_prev.close();
  infowindow_prev = infowindow;
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
 }



 function dataCallback(data, tabletop) {
var benchmarked = data['Benchmarked Buildings'].elements;
// var allBuildings = data['All Buildings over 10000 sq ft'].elements;
benchmarked.forEach(function(building) {
  // console.log(building);
  if (building.lat && building.lng) {
    addMarker(
      {
        lat: building.lat,
        lng: building.lng,
        address: building.address1,
        energyStarScore: building.energystarscore,
        energyStarYears: building['energystarcertification-yearscertified'],
        energyUseIntensity: building.weathernormalizedsiteeuikbtuft,
        propertyname: building.propertyname,
        propertyType: building['primarypropertytype-selfselected'],
        squareFootage: building.grosssquarefootage,
        yearBuilt: building.yearbuilt,
        website: building.buldingwebsite,
        // certifications: building.
        energyStrategies: building['whatarethetopthreeefficiencystrategiesyouhaveimplementedinyourbuildingifyourbuildinghasbeenwrittenupasacasestudypleaseincludethelinktoithereoremailittodenvercepdenvergov.org.']
      }
    );
  }
});
}

  Tabletop.init({
    key: dataKey,
     callback: dataCallback
  });
 })();
```

Comment: @RaeRae961 Actual way of saying thanks in SO is marking an answer as accepted or up voting it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment ;)

Comment: I did upvote it as well, but it doesn't show yet because I don't have enough reputation points yet. Thanks again.

Comment: After reviewing the code you helped me with, it turns out that something broke with the infowindow being made into that global variable. When clicking on the markers, it always comes up with the same building name and address on each marker so it's not giving the true and correct information. I don't understand why it's doing that. I somehow lost the "tabletop" data key or something maybe, I don't know. Any ideas?

Comment: With that latest revision by adding the if statement and prev. variable, that made the code work.